# Php file download is putting two lines with a line feed at the top

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers, download, linefeed

I have a script that receives a parameter then downloads a file to the clients browser. The file is not located in a folder accessible under the docent root

When my script executes pdf's work fine but word docents do not.

I have examined the files with notepad++ with show symbols on and both the pdf's and docs have two lines at the top containing a LF according to notepad++ (looks like adobe reader is more forgiving).

I have checked everything I can think of. I have tried passing the file to trim befor outputting, checked there is no whitespace before opening php tags, tried creating a file as an array looping every element and not echoing the forst two if they contain "\n",

Could this be apache set up issues?

Example Script:

```
<?php
class TrainingDatabase_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function downloadAction()
{
            $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

            // Get filepath and decode it from get param
            $filepath = urldecode( $this->_request->getParam('directory') );

            // Return the basename for save as filename
            $filename = basename($filepath);


            // Set the headers
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));

            // Make sure nothing is left in the browser
            ob_clean();
            flush();

            // Output the file
            readfile($filepath);
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the content-type as an octet-stream, try using application/msword for Word and application/pdf for PDF files. Also, does the $filepath variable contain only the path to the directory and not to the file itself? Then it could be the filesize($filepath) is messing something up

Comment: Do any of the included files have the closing `?>` at the end? As whitespace after that can cause this too.

Comment: Hi Tim, I do not have any trailing ?> tags in any of the files that make up the route. I have also ensured no whitespace in files as well. Thanks, ronnie

Comment: Hi Edwadmp, I will try the mime type suggestions today amd post my findings. The reason I used octet-stream is the file could be of any type, will try a switch based on file extension. Also $filepath contains the path and the filename, I use basename to get the filename so I can use that as the files name in the save as dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had checked every file used in the rendering of the page for closing php tags or whitespace before the opening php tags.

However I had not checked the custom Action Helpers I had created. I didn't even think to check this as I wasn't using them in this action.

These action helpers had closing php tags, having removed those it fixed the problem.

Thanks to everyone for your help!
Ronnie